# How to fetch list items in a sharepoint 2013 site from a list in an another sharepoint 2013 site?

Tags: 2013, list, jsom, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a SharePoint site A, and i would like to get the list items from a list that is in a different SharePoint site say, site B.

Note: Site A and Site B are not two subsites within in the same sitecollection. There are two entirely different Sitecollections.

I tried JSOM and Rest API, all resulted in either 403/401 error or X-Frame error Content-Not-Allowed or the "There is no app context to execute this request". I also used SP.RequestExecutor.js and even that didn't work.

I'm calling this from the home page of a sharepoint site using a content editor webpart referencing a javascript file.

I also have administrative access to both sharepoint sites. However, i don't have server-side access. So all i can do is client-side changes.

The below script is called from within a content editor webpart from 
https://ent01.sharepoint.abc.com/teams/siteA/

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://ent03.sharepoint.abc.com/teams/siteB/Lists/GetByTitle('Employees')/Items",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            //Todo
        },
        error: function (error) {
             //Todo
        }
    });
```

This didn't work, so i have also tried the sample code from MSDN for cross-domain library.

```
 var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor("https://ent03.sharepoint.abc.com/teams/siteB/");
        executor.executeAsync(
            {
              url:
                  "https://ent03.sharepoint.abc.com/teams/siteB/Lists/GetByTitle('Employees')/Items",
              method: "GET",
              headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
              success: successHandler,
              error: errorHandler
            }
        );
```

I'm actually trying to store the list data to a javascript object which i would then use it to create tasks.

Comment: Hard telling without seeing what you are doing, can you provide the code?

Comment: I hope this helps!

Comment: Do you mean you have an App and can access the Host Web but not another SiteCollection? That's by design.. I think.., an App can only access its Host Web (SiteCollection) (The site collection the App was initiated from)

Comment: As explained above, jquery call is invoked during the load of the page which is placed within the content editor web-part. So i believe the query isn't happening within an App. So i guess it is not possible to retrieve list items from another site collection without server-side configuration.

Answer (score 2):

You have the following solutions to the above problem:-

- You can use either the SharePoint feature of ["Cross Site content publishing"](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635883.aspx).
- Also, you can use Search(custom ["Result source"](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn186229.aspx)) and display the results using one of the below options:-

  1. **Content Search Webpart :** if you have less than 50 items.
  2. **Search REST API :** javaScript to hit ["REST API"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163876.aspx) for search to get the results and display if the items are more than 50 using plain JS or using any template supported frontend API.
  3. **Search Results Webpart:** the best possible way in which you can bind the result source and would also have the OOTB Pagination.

Hope this gives you several options/solutions to choose from.

Comment: The return result will contain more than 50 items.

Comment: If the results are more than 50 items I would recommend to use Search Results webpart first, if it doesn't meet your needs then you can use the Search REST API.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your situation, this might be a good case for using the Content Search Web Part.

- It gets its information from the Search Service, so crossing site/site collection boundaries is possible (as long as the user has rights to see the content - security trimming still applies).
- You can configure the query to be very specific, so you can target a single list.
- You can create custom Display Templates to display the results, so you have a great amount of control over how the results are displayed.

[Here is the first](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2012/10/using-content-search-web-part-and.html) in a series of articles by Chris O'Brien on using the Content Search Web Part, and of course there are countless other resources out there for the Googling.